# Pattern for no data in a section in collectionView/TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am contemplating on what is the recommended way to display a notice that there is no data for a specific section in a collectionView/TableView

One way is to create a special cell and to put that in instead of the data cells. That feels odd, since the "empty notice" cell doesn't correlate with the data, which means I would need to spread a lot of conditions in didSelectItem, configuring the cell, etc

Using https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet is appropriate only when the entire view is empty, not in a specific section

Another way would be (which is what I do now) to insert a UIView into the place where the data would be as a subview of the collectionview, But this also would require maintenance when reloading the data, scrolling, tapping. Also this requires calculation of where to place the view, which means I need to change it per collectionview, since it is not part of the collectionviewlayout

Is there a recommended pattern to deal with these situations?

Comment: Why not simply omit the empty section?  That's the expected pattern.

Comment: How would the user know the reason there is no data?

Comment: It's understood.  For example, if there is no address information for a contact, that section isn't visible.

Comment: For a static data yes, but for dynamic data that requires some user intervention no. If the user didn't input the address, the app must let them know

Comment: If the address was required, the app shouldn't let the user save the details without an address.  So, you'd never have a record with an empty address.  Validation happens when saving data, not when displaying data.

Comment: you are getting too much into specifics, address was your example. Think comments, photos, links, reviews, tags, friends - things that the user needs to do something for them to appear, and if they don't, it is the app's job to make the user do something, otherwise the experience of the user will be ruined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't have that section at all if the section contains empty data. Reduce section count by 1 at `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` datasource method and recheck the cell to be displayed during `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` datasource method.

Comment: But I want to tell the use there is no data, so she won't wonder why that view is different than the others

Answer (score 0):

In reply to you, I think you would have some type of "Add" button to add comments, photos, friends, etc.  Make the option to add a comment or photo less obtrusive than taking an entire tableView row, and omit the comment or photo section, if there are no comments or photos.

If you put an "Add comment" or "Add photo" row while displaying details, users will likely get tired of unnecessarily reading that, as they use the app.

Note that tableViews generally handle insertion in [editing mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html), and when not editing, **no section is shown if it is empty**.